# Setting Group Policy for Default App by File Type for two different programs

Tags: pdf, group-policy, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I'd like to set a group policy object to define the default application for PDF files.  Simple enough, except our users use two different versions of Adobe (Reader and Acrobat,) as some need to edit PDF's and some don't.  It does not make very much sense to divide the machines or users into separate OUs for this, and making Reader the default would be bad for Acrobat users' QoL.  Is there a way to set a preferential default, set the default to Acrobat if its installed, and if its not installed set it to reader?  Or is the only way to achieve that functionality to apply different GPO's to different OUs?

Comment: For what version of Windows OS?

Comment: The Domain Controller has Windows Server 2008, the workstations are mostly 10 but there's still a few Windows 7 machines in the environment.

Comment: You can use WMI filtering for separating which OS gets which policy and use security filtering for the machines that get which policy that sets which defaults. You don't need to separate everything into separate OUs but you will likely need a policy that sets the defaults association for the Adobe versions since WIndows 10 uses the XML file method but not 100% certain on the Windows 7 as I'd need to think about some more and verify how to association with GPO but maybe a script would be best.... You have some options and it's possible without OUs to separate.